# Authorization has been denied for this request error

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I'm using an authorization token to access a JSON api web service. I'm using the code below to try and do so and it returns this error in Q title , so can someone help me to provide step by step solution with sample code:

Here is webservice link i'm calling:
http://api.nokhbatalatbaq.com/api/Packages/1/Comments

```
public class CommentsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

HttpURLConnection httpcon;
String url = null;
String data = null;
String   results = null;
Activity a ;

private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;
Throwable error;

public CommentsAsyncTask(Activity context,String url) {
    this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    this.a=context;
    this.url=url;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://api.nokhbatalatbaq.com/api/Packages/1/Comments" );
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    String requestBody ="access_token=<OMITTED>&username=<OMITTED>&userID=3&issued=Sun, 14 Feb 2016 05:31:18 GMT&expires=Sun, 28 Feb 2016 05:31:18 GMT";

    try {
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

/* Checking response */
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         results = "ERROR";
        results = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("STACK", "Response::" + results);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    return results;
}




@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    Log.d("error", result);
    Toast.makeText(a, result,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Comment: Why did you think it was a good idea to post your authorization token anywhere online?

Comment: Then why ask users to not use yours? Just sounds like you're asking for abuse of the system, in any case.

Comment: Where do you obtain access token?? You need to send the obtained token with your request.

Comment: i have get it manually from api developer , so how i can send it with request , full sample please .

Comment: You can get it through some responses from api. API could provide the token via some responses but you must know which request given those tokens